# Upness and downness

Tags: quarks, elementary-particles

There is a flavour for almost any type of quark [from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics))]:

- **isospin**: $I_3=\frac{1}{2}((n_u-n_{\bar{u}})-(n_d-n_{\bar{d}}))$
- **strangeness**: $S = −(n_s − n_{\bar s})$
- **charmness**: $C = (n_c − n_{\bar c})$
- **bottomness**: $B′ = −(n_b − n_{\bar b})$
- **topness**: $T = (n_t − n_{\bar t})$

(where $n_i$ is the number of quarks $i$, and $\bar i$ is anti-$i$)

Why are the up and down quarks in this sense special, that they do not give rise to a **upness** nor **downness**, but rather to **isospin**.

Comment: What would you describe as isospin?

Comment: @Countto10, the third component of the isospin, it is a quantum number related to the strong interaction.

Comment: Historical reasons. Isospin was described before the theory of strong interaction with quarks, and is linked to properties of protons and neutrons.

Comment: @Slereah, but why only one then? Don't you need two: one for the upness and one for the downess? Or is the other one the baryon number?

Comment: It would be more logical to throw out isospin in favour of upness and downness. There is nothing special about the up and down quarks other than that historically they were the only constituents of the known-at-the-time hadrons. Knowing the above five quantum numbers as well as total baryon number is equivalent to knowing the six more systematic quantum numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be more logical to add upness and downness... It helps pedagogically with the strong force, but once you get the weak force in here and discover that there is no conservation of upness, downness,  charmness, strangeness, topness, or bottomness, you presently pedagogically fall back on "but we have a *weak* isospin and a *weak* hypercharge that we can still use!" -- and if you didn't introduce isospin or hypercharge at the start of the strong force class, nobody would know what that means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a hadron with only up and down quarks. Given its isospin

$$I_3=\frac{1}{2}\left((n_u-n_\bar{u})-(n_d-n_\bar{d})\right)$$

and its charge

$$Q=I_3=\frac{2}{3}(n_u-n_\bar{u}) - \frac{1}{3}(n_d - n_\bar{d})$$

we can know what you called upness and downness, i.e. $n_u-n_\bar{u}$, and $n_d-n_\bar{d}$, respectively, modulo a sign perhaps. Then, as often, habits inherited from historical development will not change because the improvement would be perceived as too small to be worth it.